# Can I dynamically delegate the variable id and delegate many variable "id" toggether with a function by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, delegates, live

```
var left=10;
var right=50;
$("#leftori").attr("id",left);
$("#rightori").attr("id",right);//change the id

$(document).delegate('div[id^='+left+']', 'mouseenter',function() {
  alert("left ok!");
  var newleft=left+1;
  $("#"+left).attr("id","newleft"};//change the id
  left=newleft;
 }
$(document).delegate('div[id^='+right+']', 'mouseenter',function() {
  alert("right ok!");
  var newright=right+1;
  $("#"+right).attr("id","newright");
  right=right+1;
}

<body>
<div id="leftori" class="div01"></div>
<div id="rightori" class="div01"></div>
</body>
```

**The Questions are:**

1. How can I delegate the dynamical "id" on the new div which changed the id attribute on the second mouseenter event?
2. I want to combine the selector with the `id^=left` or `id^=right` in the same delegate function . Can any method to make it? For example:

   `$(document).delegate('div[id^='+left+']' || 'div[id^='+right+']' , 'mouseenter',function() {...}`

But it cannot work well...How can I fix it or not have other method but to write in two delegate functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you don't change the ID of any DOM element - there are far better ways to  keep "data" on a DOM element ....

How about something like this :

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="leftori" class="left"></div>
   <div id="rightori" class="right"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var left=10;
var right=50;
// store the data
$("#leftori").data("num",left);
$("#rightori").data("num",right);

$('#container').on('mouseenter','div',function() { 
    // update the data on mouseenter
    if ($(this).hasClass('left')){
        console.log('left');
        left++;
        $(this).data('num',left);
        console.log(left); 
        // or console.log($(this).data('num')); to access the new number
    } else if($(this).hasClass('right')) {
        console.log('right');
        right++;
        $(this).data('num',right);
        console.log(right);
        // or console.log($(this).data('num')); to access the new number
    }
});
```

Incase you are not aware - the `console.log` command logs the output to the browsers javascript console of a debugger ([firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)).

docs

- [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) -> replacement for delegate in jQuery 1.7
- [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) -> storing info on DOM elements
- [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) -> check if the DOM element has a specific class

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/8RhbB/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help sincerely!This is a very good work and works very good!Thanks a lot!I will try to study the console usage on the web.Thanks!